# Scala: Replace all space characters with %20

Tags: scala

I need to replace all space characters with %20. I wrote this in Scala

```
strToConvert.map(c => if (Character.isSpaceChar(c)) "%20" else c).mkString
```

Is there any better way to do this in Scala?

[Edit]
Lets assume replaceAll is not available and we'd like to implement algorithm similar to replaceAll method

Comment: `strToConvert.replaceAll("""\s+""", "%20")`

Comment: Without using `replaceAll`, I think you have it about right. The only thing I can suggest is replacing `Character.isSpaceChar(c)` with `c.isSpaceChar`. Note that, either way, you can potentially have problems with space characters that do not map to a single `Char` value (so that the space character is represented by multiple surrogate characters).

Comment: @MikeAllen Thanks for the tip! Is there any difference between Character.isSpaceChar and c.isSpaceChar besides the fact that latter requires less typing.

Comment: None. The shorter form invokes the longer form (through an implicit conversion of `c` from `Char` to `RichChar`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [`String.replaceAll(what_to_replace, with_what)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)).

eg. to replace single whitespace with `%20`

```
scala> val input = "this is my http request          execute me"
input: String = this is my http request          execute me

scala> input.replaceAll(" ", "%20")
res1: String = this%20is%20my%20http%20request%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20execute%20me
```

**or use `\\s` regex (matches single whitespace character)**

```
scala> input.replaceAll("\\s", "%20")
res2: String = this%20is%20my%20http%20request%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20execute%20me
```

If you want **multiple whitespaces to replace to one single `%20`**, then use `\\s+` which matches sequence of one or more whitespace characters

```
scala> input.replaceAll("\\s+", "%20")
res3: String = this%20is%20my%20http%20request%20execute%20me
```